# Why does the pandas Dataframe version of a sparse matrix not work with RandomOverSampler from imblearn when the documentation says it accepts both?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, imblearn

Spent a painful night debugging

```
import pandas as pd
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler


x_trainvec_rand, y_train_rand = RandomOverSampler(random_state=0).fit_resample(pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(x_trainvec), y_train)   

print(x_trainvec_rand)
```

where x_trainvec is a csr sparse matrix and y_train is a pandas Dataframe, the dimensions of both in Dataframes are (75060 x 52651) and (75060 x 1), with the error 'ValueError: Shape of passed values is (290210, 1), indices imply (290210, 52651)'.

When suddenly I decided to try just

```
import pandas as pd
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler


x_trainvec_rand, y_train_rand = RandomOverSampler(random_state=0).fit_resample(x_trainvec, y_train)   

print(x_trainvec_rand)
```

and somehow it worked.

Any ideas as to why?

Documentation says:

```
fit_resample(X, y)[source]
Resample the dataset.

Parameters
X : {array-like, dataframe, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
Matrix containing the data which have to be sampled.

y : array-like of shape (n_samples,)
Corresponding label for each sample in X.
```

Comment: Just because it says it can work with `sparse_matrix` does not mean it can also work with  `pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(x_trainvec)`.  You could look at two things.  1) how `fit_resample` handles a sparse.matrix`, and 2) how the dataframe sparse is different.  I believe `pandas` has gone through several versions of sparse.

Comment: https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/install.html appears to be quite old, requiring `numpy 1.17`, `scipy 1.3`, `pandas 1.0.5`.  That means it knows nothing about the current `pandas` handling of sparse matrices.

Comment: I see, I suppose this means that I'm prob better off defining a resampling function with libraries that use the updated ver of pandas than using imblearn's. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @hpaulj those are *minimum* versions - the latest release was in May. that said I have no idea how well maintained imbalanced-learn is or if it can be used in the way the OP is attempting to, so your first comment certainly seems on point too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says it accepts

```
X : {array-like, dataframe, sparse matrix}
```

That's `sparse matrix`, not sparse dataframe.  In the `imbalaced-learn` source I found tests that the sparse type had to be `csr` or `csr`, but couldn't follow further processing.

But lets look at the pandas sparse.

A sparse matrix:

```
In [105]: M = sparse.csr_matrix(np.eye(3))
In [106]: M
Out[106]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [107]: print(M)
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
```

The derived dataframe:

```
In [108]: df = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(M)
In [109]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype             
---  ------  --------------  -----             
 0   0       3 non-null      Sparse[float64, 0]
 1   1       3 non-null      Sparse[float64, 0]
 2   2       3 non-null      Sparse[float64, 0]
dtypes: Sparse[float64, 0](3)
memory usage: 164.0 bytes
In [110]: df[1]
Out[110]: 
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    0.0
Name: 1, dtype: Sparse[float64, 0]
In [111]: df[1].values
Out[111]: 
[0, 1.0, 0]
Fill: 0
IntIndex
Indices: array([1], dtype=int32)
```

The sparse dataframe storage is entirely different from the sparse matrix.  It's not a simple merger of the two classes.

I probably should have insisted on seeing the FULL traceback for the error,

```
 ValueError: Shape of passed values is (290210, 1), indices imply (290210, 52651)
```

At least it might give us/you an idea of what it is trying to do.  But on the other hand, focusing on what the documentation ACTUALLY says, rather than what you want it to say, is enough.

Comment: didn't know that sparse dataframes were different from normal dataframes, thanks for the info!